# ValidateRect vs BeginPaint

Tags: winapi

From the MSDN documentation:

> The `BeginPaint` function validates the entire client area.
>
> The `ValidateRect` function should not be called if a portion of the
> update region must be validated before the next WM_PAINT message is
> generated.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms914091.aspx)

I've been programming with Win32 API for years, and I've never thought to call the `ValidateRect` function.  A co-worker of mine today pointed that we were missing a call to `ValidateRect`, which fixed a bug we were having doing some high-speed animation using GDI (I know, an oxymoron)

Can someone tell me whether or not a call to `ValidateRect` is necessary after a `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` pair?  I have seen no documentation at MSDN that sheds light on this, and what documentation and examples I do see suggest that calling `ValidateRect` is not necessary.

Comment: Pretty unclear.  You should only call ValidateRect when you directly draw to the window and thus don't need WM_PAINT.  Not uncommon in animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary. `BeginPaint` is used when you are validating the area because you handled it (painted it) in `WM_PAINT`.

`ValidateRect` is more to "cancel invalidation", usually after painting directly on the window without `WM_PAINT` or because something changed and you no longer want to be issued a pending `WM_PAINT`.

The fact that it fixed a bug likely means there's something else going on, and this accidentally fixed it (maybe by reducing the number of `WM_PAINT` messages?), or wrong observations (for example you changed 2 things but this one got the attention instead of the other which is the actual fix).

Comment: This is exactly what I told the coder who brought this to my attention, but the piece of code we were debugging is some complex that it is difficult to really tell.  Unfortunately, using a debugger in any meaningful away tends to interfere with painting related code :(